# Adobe XD Plugin Support

Tags: node.js, websocket, adobe, adobe-xd

Is there a way to register an interaction within a Adobe XD document?

For example if a user presses a button, can we send a response to an external server notifying that that event happened?

Reading the Adobe XD plugin documents it seems that most API's are used for read only.

Any help appreciated and maybe pointers on what's needed (websockets etc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can the plugin API gives you several methods for interacting with objects in the scene and interface elements.

[Read the docs](https://www.adobe.io/xd/uxp/uxp/reference-js/Global%20Members/Data%20Transfers/) for more info